# How to check if any row has negative values by leaving out selected rows?

Tags: r

Below is the dataframe I get by running a query. Please note that df1 is a dynamic dataframe and it might return either an empty df or partial df with not all quarters as seen below:

```
df1
   FISC_QTR_VAL                      Revenue
1       2014-Q1                         0.00
2       2014-Q2                    299111.86
3       2014-Q3                    174071.98
4       2014-Q4                    257655.30
5       2015-Q1                         0.00
6       2015-Q2                    317118.63
7       2015-Q3                    145461.88
8       2015-Q4                    162972.41
9       2016-Q1                     96896.04
10      2016-Q2                    135058.78
11      2016-Q3                    111773.77
12      2016-Q4                    138479.28
13      2017-Q1                    169276.04
```

I would want to check the values of all the rows in Revenue column and see if any value is 0 or negative excluding 2014-Q1 row

Also, the df1 is dynamic and will contain only 12 quarters of data i.e. when I reach next qtr i.e. 2017-Q2, the Revenue associated with 2014-Q2 becomes 0 and it will look like this:

```
df1
   FISC_QTR_VAL                      Revenue
1       2014-Q1                         0.00
2       2014-Q2                         0.00
3       2014-Q3                    174071.98
4       2014-Q4                    257655.30
5       2015-Q1                         0.00
6       2015-Q2                    317118.63
7       2015-Q3                    145461.88
8       2015-Q4                    162972.41
9       2016-Q1                     96896.04
10      2016-Q2                    135058.78
11      2016-Q3                    111773.77
12      2016-Q4                    138479.28
13      2017-Q1                    169276.04
14      2017-Q2                    146253.64
```

In the above case, I would need to check all rows for the Revenue column by excluding 2014-Q1 and 2014-Q2

And this goes on as quarter progresses

Need your help to generate the code which would dynamically do all the above steps of excluding the row(s) and check only the rows that matter for a particular quarter

Currently, I am using the below code:

```
        #Taking the first df1 into consideration which has 2017-Q1 as the last quarter
        startQtr <- "2014-Q2" #This value is dynamically achieved and will change as we move ahead. Next quarter, the value changes to 2014-Q3 and so on     
        if(length(df1[["FISC_QTR_VAL"]][nrow(df1)-11] == startQtr) == 1){

        if(nrow(df1[df1$Revenue < 0,]) == 0 & nrow(df1[df1$Revenue == 0,]) == 0){

          df1 <- df1 %>% slice((nrow(df1)-11):(nrow(df1)))
          }
        }
```

The first IF loop checks if there is data in df1
If the df is empty,

```
df1[["FISC_QTR_VAL"]][nrow(df1)-10] == startQtr
```

condition would return numeric(0) whose length would be 0 and hence the condition fails

If not, then it goes to the next IF loop and checks for -ve and 0 values in Revenue column. But it does for all the rows. I want 2014-Q1 excluded in this case, and going forward to the future quarters, would want the condition to be dynamic as explained above.

Also, I do not want to slice the dataset before the if condition as the code would throw an error if the initial dataframe df1 returns 1 row or 2 rows and we try to slice those further

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: difficult to analyze the output as it is a long drawn process of linear regressions. The above method is just the start point where we input the data and check for anomalies like 0 or negative values in select rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a few functions from the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

Here's a toy data set to work with:

```
d <- data.frame(
  FISC_QTR_VAL = c("2015-Q1", "2014-Q2", "2014-Q1", "2015-Q2"),
  Revenue      = c(100, 200, 0, 0)
)
d
#>   FISC_QTR_VAL Revenue
#> 1      2015-Q1     100
#> 2      2014-Q2     200
#> 3      2014-Q1       0
#> 4      2015-Q2       0
```

Notice that `FISC_QTR_VAL` is intentionally out of order (as a precaution).

Next, set variables for the current year and quarter (you'll see why separate in a moment):

```
current_year <- 2014
current_quarter <- 2
```

Then run the following:

```
d %>%
  separate(FISC_QTR_VAL, c("year", "quarter"), sep = "-Q") %>% 
  arrange(year, quarter) %>%
  slice(which(year == current_year & quarter == current_quarter):n()) %>% 
  filter(Revenue <= 0)
#>   year quarter Revenue
#> 1 2015       2       0
```

First, we `separate()` the `FISC_QTR_VAL` into separate `year` and `quarter` variables for (a) a tidy data set and (b) a way to order the data in case it's out of order (as in the toy used here). We then `arrange()` the data so that it's ordered by `year` and `quarter`. Then, we `slice()` away any quarters prior to the current one, and then `filter()` to return all rows where `Revenue <= 0`.

To alternatively get, for example, a count of the number of rows that are returned, you can pipe on something like `nrow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `subset` function an option for you?

```
exclude.qr <- c("2014-Q1", "2014-Q2")

df <- data.frame(
  FISC_QTR_VAL = c("2014-Q1", "2014-Q2", "2014-Q3", "2014-Q4"),
  Revenue = c(0.00, 299111.86, 174071.98, 257655.30))

subset(
  df,
  FISC_QTR_VAL != exclude.qr, Revenue > 0)
```

You can easily create exclue.qr dynamically, e.g. via `paste` an `years <- 2010:END`.

I hope this is helpfull!